# How can I check the connection of Mongoid

Tags: mongodb, connection, mongoid, database

Does Mongoid has any method like `ActiveRecord::Base.connected?`?
I want to check if the connection that's accessible.

Answer (score 2):

We wanted to implement a health check for our running Mongoid client that tells us whether the established connection is still alive. This is what we came up with:

```
Mongoid.default_client.database_names.present?
```

Basically it takes your current client and tries to query the databases on its connected server. If this server is down, you will run into a timeout, which you can catch.

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
    def check_mongoid_connection
        mongoid_config = File.read("#{Rails.root}/config/mongoid.yml")
        config = YAML.load(mongoid_config)[Rails.env].symbolize_keys
        host, db_name, user_name, password = config[:host], config[:database], config[:username], config[:password]
        port = config[:port] || Mongo::Connection::DEFAULT_PORT

        db_connection = Mongo::Connection.new(host, port).db(db_name)
        db_connection.authenticate(user_name, password) unless (user_name.nil? || password.nil?)
        db_connection.collection_names
        return { status: :ok }
    rescue Exception => e
        return { status: :error, data: { message: e.to_s } }
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

snrlx's answer is great.

I use following in my puma config file, FYI:

```
before_fork do
  begin
    # load configuration
    Mongoid.load!(File.expand_path('../../mongoid.yml', __dir__), :development)

    fail('Default client db check failed, is db connective?') unless Mongoid.default_client.database_names.present?
  rescue => exception
    # raise runtime error
    fail("connect to database failed: #{exception.message}")
  end
end
```

One thing to remind is the default `server_selection_timeout` is [30 seconds](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/master/tutorials/mongoid-installation/), which is too long for db status check at least in development, you can modify this in your mongoid.yml.